# kendo mvc editortemplate not populating viemodel properties from the grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-grid

The kendo grid is populated as expected, displaying the `ConfigurationSettings` as detail rows, as expected, but when trying to edit the row, the viewModel's state is different, some of the previously populated properties are null when the edit popup is displayed. Is there a kendo "trick" or additional wiring needed?

#### grid

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ConfiguationViewModel>()
          .Name("configurationGrid")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Width(150).Hidden(true);
              columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
              columns.Bound(c => c.ConfigurationType).ClientTemplate("#= ConfigurationType.ConfigurationTypeName  #").EditorTemplateName("ConfigurationType");
              columns.Bound(c => c.HasParentConfiguration);
              columns.Bound(c => c.CanOverride);
              columns.Bound(c => c.IsActive);
              columns.Command(command =>
              {
                  command.Edit().Text(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { title = "Edit Configuration" });
                  command.Destroy().Text(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { title = "Delete Configuration" });
              }).Width(210);
          })
          .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
                                        .TemplateName("Configuration").Window(w => w.Width(860).Resizable(r => r.Enabled(true)))
                                        .ConfirmDelete("Are you sure you want to delete this configuration?")
                                        .DisplayDeleteConfirmation("Configuration deleted"))
          .Pageable(pager => pager
              .Input(false)
              .Numeric(true)
              .Info(true)
              .PreviousNext(true)
              .Refresh(true)
              .PageSizes(new[] { 10, 15, 20 }))
          .ClientDetailTemplateId("configDetailTemplate")
          .Sortable(sortable =>
          {
              sortable.SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn);
          })
          .Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Enabled(false))
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .PageSize(20)
              .Events(events => events.Error("handleErrors").Sync("sync_handler"))
              .Model(model => model.Id(c => c.Id))
              .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Configuration"))
              .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "Configuration"))
              .Update(update => update.Action("Edit", "Configuration"))
              .Destroy(delete => delete.Action("Delete", "Configuration"))
          ))
```

#### view models when grid is displayed initially

```
   public class ConfiguationViewModel
   {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

     ...

    public virtual ICollection<ConfigurationSettingViewModel> ConfigurationSettings { get; set; } = new HashSet<ConfigurationSettingViewModel>();

  }

  // detail rows view model
  public class ConfigurationSettingViewModel
  {
    public int ConfigurationId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Value { get; set; }
  }
```

#### template used for the grid's `EditorTemplate`

Using @Model.Property yields a null for the properties (that were populated in the grid).
  For example, Trying to display a date property with @Model.DateCreated displays the default date value but if I use the html helper `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateCreated)` a datepicker with the correct value displays

```
  @model  ConfiguationViewModel

 <div class="form-horizontal" style="padding: 12px 4px;">
    <h4>Configuration</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            ...
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 18px;">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateCreated, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" }) : <text>@Model.DateCreated</text><br />
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModifiedById, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label text-muted" }) : <text class="text-muted">@Model.ModifiedById</text> <br />
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateModified, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label text-muted" }) : <text class="text-muted">@Model.DateModified</text>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            //NPE
            @if (Model != null && Model.ConfigurationSettings.Any())
            {
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Configuration Id</th>
                            <th scope="col">Key</th>
                            <th scope="col">Value</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        // NPE HERE
                        @foreach (var config in Model.ConfigurationSettings)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <h2>@config.ConfigurationId</h2>
                                </td>
                                <td>@config.Key</td>
                                <td>@config.Value</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            }
            else
            {
                <div class="alert alert-warn">No Settings Defined </div>

            }
     </div>
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration of the kendo grid?

Comment: @tattarrattat updated the question with the grid declaration